# A question about the space $c_0$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Suppose $x,x_n\in c_0$ with norm 1 such that $\|x_n+x\|\to 2$. Let $f\in c_0^*$ with $\|f\|=1$ such that $f(x)=1$. I want to check if $$d(x_n,A)\to 0, \text{ where }A=\{y\in c_0: \|y\|=1, f(y)=1\}$$

I tried to find a counterexample to disprove it, but could not do so. Neither can I prove it. Any suggestion please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Counterexample:
\begin{align*}
x &= (1, 1, 0, 0, \ldots) \\
x_n &= \begin{cases}(1, 0, 0, 0, \ldots) & \text{if } n \text{ is even} \\ (0, 1, 0, 0, \ldots) & \text{if } n \text{ is odd}.\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Note that $\|x + x_n\| = 2$.

Further, let $f(y)$ be the first coordinate of $y \in c_0$. Note that $f \in c_0^*$. It corresponds to the sequence $(1, 0, 0, \ldots)$ in $\ell^1$, and has norm $1$. We also have $f(x) = 1$.

However, $f(x + x_n)$ oscillates between $1$ and $2$. In particular, if $n$ is odd, then $f(x_n) = 0$, and if $y \in A$, then $\|y - x_n\|$ is at least $1$. Thus, $d(x_n, A)$ does not tend to $0$.

Comment: Shouldn't it read "... $n$ is odd, then $f(x_n) = 0$, and ..." ? There is something odd.

Comment: @Hanno After 8 hours sleep, I concur.